# Group-Object in powershell, select first item in each group

Tags: powershell

Given the following script.

```
$module = # get path
$code = get-childitem $module -recurse -include *.dll
$list = $code | group-object -Property Name
$list
```

I retreive the following:

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                         
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                         
    4 FileA...                  {A, B, C, D}
    2 FileB...                  {X, Z}
    1 FileX...                  {R}
```

How do I select the first item in each group.
I want to group by the file name, but actually retrieve the first file (full path) in each group.

I want to obtain `A,X,R etc`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it:

```
$list | %{$_.Group[0].FullName}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This was the last piece of my puzzle with getting the last file of each grouping copied during a Bamboo deployment when there were multiple copies of the same DLLs being copied over (overwriting each other).